# How to store list of associated entities in LevelDB

Tags: java, database, nosql, leveldb

Say I have an entity Client which has many entities Product. I am figuring out the best way to store these information in LevelDB.

```
class Client {

     String clientId;
     String clientName;
     List<Product> products;
}

class Product {

     String productId;
     Client client;
     String productName;
}
```

I have thought about marshaling these data to xml/json and persisting to LevelDB, yet it takes effort and might not be a good approach. Can you suggest me other solutions?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you to seperate this business model into 3 types of data(like 3 tables in RMDB).

One is **Client** entity, serialize the entity to json, store it using client ID as key(with prefix "client_"), like "client_1", "client_2", the relation products is not stored in Client entity. Sample data: `client_1 => {clientId: 1, clientName: "name"}`

Second is **Product** entity, change client property to clientId. Serialize and store just like you do to Client. Sample data: `product_1 => {productId: 1, productName: "book"}`

The third is the **Relation**, using client Id as key(with prefix "client_product_"), like "client_product_1", "client_product_2", etc. Implode all client Ids of its products into a string. Sample data: `client_product_1 => 1,2,3,4,5`

However, you may want to use some database that is designed to store "relation"(lists, sets, hashmaps), try SSDB(https://github.com/ideawu/ssdb), SSDB is a network wrapper of LevelDB, and is suitable for storing colletion data.